GitLab の API を使用したファイルダウンロードが失敗する
あるプロジェクトのTestというディレクトリ配下にあるaaa.txtというファイルをAPIにより取得(ファイルをローカルにダウンロード)したいです。
コマンドプロンプトにて以下のコマンドを試しましたが "404 commit not found" が返信されます。何が問題でしょうか。
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: access_token" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/プロジェクトのID/repository/files/Test%2Faaa%2Etxt/raw?ref=master"

ファイルパスについてはURLエンコードするとあったので、/ は %2F、 . は %2E としています。

GitLab のAPIドキュメントを見る限り、file_pathの指定はURLEncodeされたファイルパスで間違いないでしょう。
ファイルパスとしてはTest/aaa.txtであるので、file_pathとしてエンコードしてあるTest%2Faaa%2Etxtを指定するまでは分かりますが、末尾へ更に/rawをつける必要性がなさそうです。
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: access_token" \
  "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/プロジェクトのID/repository/files/Test%2Faaa%2Etxt?ref=master"


refをmainにしたところ成功しました

このコメントだと、「回答として提示したURLを使用したうえでrefをmasterからmainにした」のか「もともとの質問文にあるURLにあるrefをmasterからmainに変えた」に変えたのかがいまいちはっきりしません。
特に後者なのであれば、自身の回答として投稿するのが望ましいです。
